# Mask brackets in Jade - AngularJS Syntax

Tags: angularjs, pug

How to write this in Jade? Especially the .get() makes me problems.

```
<li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.get() track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }"></li>
```

Example from:
https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-breadcrumbs

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jade this line

```
<li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.get() track by breadcrumb.path" ng-class="{ active: $last }"></li>
```

will become

```
li(ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.get() track by breadcrumb.path", ng-class="{ active: $last }")
```

Comment: Ahh ok, I have made a simple mistake! Thank you!

Comment: Need to wait 8 minutes :)